# Accessing Current Users Data Only

Tags: node.js, express

I'm working on a couple of API endpoints in an Express app of mine for note taking. So far I've built out authentication using JWT and I'm now trying to create CRUD endpoints for the authenticated users notes. The problem I'm running into is creating an association between the current logged in user, and if they have access to make changes to that item.

In my `authentication` controller I've tried setting something on the request that states who the authenticated user is:

```
exports.signin = function(req, res, next) {
  req.currentUser = req.user;
  res.send({ token: tokenForUser(req.user)  });
}
```

I've setup a method in my user model that checks if the object is the same:

```
userSchema.methods.canAccess = function(object) {
  return this.equals(object) ||
  (object.owner && object.owner == this.id)
}
```

And then finally on my route for creating a note my goal is to be able to do something like `if ( req.currentUser.canAccess(req.user) )` but the problem I'm running into is that `currentUser` is undefined.

I feel like I'm making a crucial mistake somewhere along the lines here and any help would be appreciated.

**Update (Routes)**

```
module.exports = function(app) {
  app.get('/', requireAuth, (req, res) => {
    res.send({ message: `Welcome back ${res.req.user.email}` })
  });

  app.post('/signin', requireSignIn, Authentication.signin);
  app.post('/signup', Authentication.signup);

  app.post('/notes/create', requireSignIn, Notes.create);
}
```

Comment: Why are you not using ``req.user``  directly?

Comment: @DevangNaghera `req.user` is actually undefined, so that's probably my issue. I'm not sure how to expose that data on another endpoint. I can get it when I hit the `/signin` route, but not my `/notes/create` route

Answer (score 0):

I dun think there's a variable name called req.currentUser in default express request.

You store data in GET request in params/header/query and access them in req.query/req.params/req.headers.

For POST/PUT/DELETE store data in body and you can get them out in req.body.

Can show me your postman api send request and the req data?